# How to use With clause for Neo4j Cypher subquery formulation?

Tags: neo4j, subquery, cypher

I trying to create a simple cypher `query` that should find all instances in the graph matching roughly this structure `(BlogPost A) -> (Term) <- (BlogPost B)`. This means, I am trying all pairs of blog posts that are flagged with the same term and moreover count the number of terms. A term is a mechanism of categorization in this context.

Here is my **query** proposal:

```
MATCH (blogA:content {entitySubType:'blog'}) 
WITH blogA MATCH (blogA) -[]-> (t:term) <-[]- (blogB:content) 
WHERE blogB.entitySubType='blog' AND NOT (ID(blogA) = ID(blogB))  
RETURN ID(blogA), ID(blogB), count(t) ;
```

This query ends with null after ~1 day.

Is the uasge of blogA in the subquery not possible in the way I am using it? When using the same query with limits I do get reuslts:

```
MATCH (blogA:content {entitySubType:'blog'}) 
WITH blogA 
LIMIT 10 
MATCH (blogA) -[]-> (t:term) <-[]- (blogB:content) 
WHERE blogB.entitySubType='blog' AND NOT (ID(blogA) = ID(blogB))  
RETURN ID(blogA), ID(blogB), count(t) 
LIMIT 20;
```

My Neo4j Instance has ~500GB RAM and the whole graph inclduing all properties is ~30 GB with ~15 million vertices in total, whereas there are 101k blog vertices and 108k terms.

I would be grateful for every hint about possible problems or **suggestions** for improvements.

Comment: Do you have an index or unique constraint on :content(entitySubType)? Have you considered adding a :Blog label on :content nodes with the 'blog' entitySubType? And what kind of nodes do :term nodes connect with? Also do you want mirrored results (blogA and blogB nodes occurring twice but with switching which variable they appear)?

Comment: it would also good to use a relationship-type if there is a sensible one between blog and term. In general be aware that you are potentially computing 101k^2 pairs. Are you using Neo4j Enterprise with the slotted/compiled runtime?

Comment: @InverseFalcon There is no index on entitySubType. The point is the structure of the graph is given. So I cannot alter it. I just can use whats there. Optimally I do not want to have mirrored results, but if it is faster they can be included.

Comment: @MichaelHunger sadly only the community edition in place and never hurt of the slotted compile runtime so far

Comment: Without an index on `:content(entitySubType)` the query will have to do a label scan on :content and do property access to find all those that are blogs, that could be one source of slowdown. How many :content nodes are in the graph, and of those, how many are blogs?

Comment: @InverseFalcon #content 13,3 million and #blogs 101k whereas blogs are content with entitiysubtype blog. I will try to get an index on the property. But any idea why I get the null? I mean I understand long runtimes but can understand the null.

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure to consume that query with a client driver (e.g. Java) that can stream the billions of results. Here is a query that would use the compiled runtime which should be fastest and most memory efficient.

```
MATCH (blogA:Blog)-[:TAGGED]->(t:Term)<-[:TAGGED]-(blogB:Blog)
WHERE blogA <> blogB 
RETURN ID(blogA), ID(blogB), count(t);
```

Comment: Thx for the reply. Could you briefly explain why your query should be fastest and memory effiecient? My thoughts using WITH were to use pieplining. One bloge node should be pipelined into the subquery, so that at first all blogs are queried as starting points of the "local" subqueries.    And I am executing the query via a cypher script executed via the cypher-shell from a bash terminal and the result shall be piped into a file. This should work, right? Any other suggestions?